# In playwright How to extract from the DOM

Tags: javascript, playwright

Hey guys In playwright I'm having a hard time extracting something from the DOM

I have this in the DOM and I want to take what title is equal to and put it into a const

`<label   title="Change to False"   > </label>`

The instructions that I'm gathering from playwright are all saying to use the evaluate but I have no idea how to fill in the rest

so far I have this

`const disableButtonLocator = page.locator('.docblock-argstable-body tr:nth-of-type(2) label');`

`const titleState = disableButtonLocator.evaluate((ele) => {    });`

Comment: did you try locator.getAttribute("title")?

Comment: So when I do this:

```const disableButton = page.locator('.docblock-argstable-body tr:nth-of-type(2) label');```

```const state = disableButton.getAttribute('title');```

```console.log(state);```

I get 
Promise { <pending> }

Comment: Ohhhhhhh Wait it worked !!!

```const state = await disableButton.getAttribute('title');```

Comment: Had to add the await !! Awesome thanks @itronic1990 You really helped me out with this!

Answer (score 1):

With the help of @itronic1990 the solution to this issue is the following which does work for me

`<label   title="Change to False"   > </label>`

`const disableButtonLocator = page.locator('.docblock-argstable-body tr:nth-of-type(2) label');`

`const state = await disableButtonLocator.getAttribute('title');`

The above getAttribute will extract the title from the DOM